# Syntax error ,I have tried to load my django project on a production server

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried to load my project on a production server,I have the below syntax error for something that was working fine in test environment,any help here?

I cant see why I have the error

> f'accounts/emails/{template}.html', context) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

here is the code

```
def send_mail(to, template, context):
    html_content = render_to_string(f'accounts/emails/{template}.html', context)
    text_content = render_to_string(f'accounts/emails/{template}.txt', context)
```

Error Traceback

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f00e7044158>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 379, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 396, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/grouped/teroexamplecom/teroexamplecom/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
        url(r'^', include('toys.urls')),
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/grouped/teroexamplecom/toys/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
        from toys import views as toysviews
      File "/home//grouped/toys/views.py", line 100, in <module>
        from .utils import (
      File "/home//toys/utils.py", line 9
        html_content = render_to_string(f'accounts/emails/{template}.html', context)
                                                                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**`f-string`**](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) notation has introduced in **Python 3.6**. It won't be available for below Python3.6

#### Soluation-1

Upgrade your python version to Python3.6 or higher

#### Solution-2

use [**`format()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method

```
def send_mail(to, template, context):
    html_content = render_to_string('accounts/emails/{template}.html'.format(template=template), context)
    text_content = render_to_string('accounts/emails/{template}.txt'.format(template=template), context)
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried to upvote, but the system didnt consider It since I am New to stackoverflow. Is there an other way to accept ?

Comment: there is a ***tick button*** near upvote/downvote button. Use it :) For detailed info, [Refer this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/397232)

Comment: Yes,I saw  :) ,I have this message when I tried ."Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."